# Temp table in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

I have a table of user ids that is huge.
I have an array of user ids that I want.
I have two tables that have a foreign user id key.

What is the best way to get this information performance wise?

Ideally in SQL the final result would be somewhat like this (null values if there is no user ID in one table but not the other):

```
userid  table1value table2value
1        null          12
5        123           null
```

Comment: Where does your array come from, and where is the temp table mentioned in the title?

Comment: I only know how to do this using a temp table in SQL.  The array is passed in through a function.  It is an array of ints.

Comment: is there a reason you want to use the temp table instead of simply doing something like usersData.where(u => usersArray.Contains(u.id)). Not 100% sure if linq to entities can parse that to 1 query but the db class we use does it so I assume it does too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue last year and then when it came to performance, then instead of taking temp table for holding records (application end or service end) O moved to LINQ to SQL and made a stored procedure and called it through entities like LINQ to stored procedure =). And my stored procedure did all and returned only those records that I wanted and I did paging to at the stored procedure end so that I got limited data at a time rather than all data at application.

Do let me know if you need any help in that. I will give a code snippet too.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, LINQ to Entities doesn't have a way to create a temp table on the fly...  I think the closest thing would be to use LINQ to Objects with a class or generating an anonymous type.

Or, do it in a stored proc, and import the proc into the object context, and have your code call the proc.  The proc can create a temp table, or whatever it wants.

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

Well, LINQ allows you to join collections (entities) much like SQL does, so you could craft a few outer joins to get the data, and that SHOULD translate to a relatively efficient SQL statement when given to [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework). Here's a small example:

```
var results = from u in UserDataSource
   join t1 in Table1DataSource on u.UserId = t1.UserId into gj
   from jt1 in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new {u.UserId, Table1Data = jt1 == null ? String.Empty : jt1.Data};
```

If the tables really are huge, or there's additional processing to perform to get the result, I would consider creating a view on the server and map it to an `Entity` in code. Then it becomes a very simple select; you just filter the view results to the user ids you want to see.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old thread, and LINQ to SQL is not exactly popular now, but it's certainly still out there.  After years of dealing with the L2S temp table issue, I just stumbled upon an alternative and easy solution to this.

I did not realize this until now --- when L2S models your stored procs (dragging them into the dbml), it adds "SET FMTONLY ON" to the SQL call.  This instructs the SQL Server to only return the metadata (format) of the result set.  When there is a temp table in the proc, it isn't able to emit the metadata during "format only", and L2S throws the dreaded, "The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected" error message.  Format Only is probably used to save L2S generation time (IDK for sure).

If you explicitly set FMTONLY to OFF, at the beginning of your temp table stored proc, then the FMTONLY ON (which L2S issues), is ignored, and L2S will properly import your temp table stored proc.  For example:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ResultViaTempTable
AS
BEGIN
    SET FMTONLY OFF -- <-- do this
    --define/fill some #tempTable
    SELECT * FROM #tempTable
END
```

MS Reference for SET FMTONLY - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-fmtonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16