# Can LINQ create a backup table/duplicate temporary table?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I am creating a Winform program. And I need to create a function where it will copy/duplicate a table as another table with a different table name perhaps. Something like an SQL SELECT INTO query?

Comment: Where do you want to create this table? In the same DB? Or you want to keep it in the memory as a table variable? Please be a little more specific in explaining what your scenario is and what you intend to do.

Comment: Thanks for the question: yes, in the same DB. Do ask me more question if needed.

Comment: Anyway, I used the .ExecuteSqlCommand for now and queried the SELECT INTO FROM command. Works, but I am still open to LINQ or entity framework options for the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, LINQ to Entities doesn't have a way to create a temp table on the fly... I think the closest thing would be to use LINQ to Objects with a class or generating an anonymous type.

Or, do it in a stored proc, and import the proc into the object context, and have your code call the proc. The proc can create a temp table, or whatever it wants.

More detail to refer this link
[Temp table in LINQ to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101705/temp-table-in-linq-to-entities)